# past simple and past progressive

Tags: verbs, word-usage

Is there any difference between;  "While you were speaking I was listening"   and   "While you spoke I listened"?

Comment: I'm guessing your question is about difference in meaning? Obviously there is a grammatical difference, but the difference in meaning, while there is one, is subtle and possibly hard to tease out.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any difference between; "While you were speaking I was
>   listening" and "While you spoke I listened"?

Yes, one shows continuous action taking place in the past, and the other shows two actions completed in the past.

Both sentences are Complex Sentences, which means each has one main (independent) clause and *at least one* subordinate (dependent) clause:

While you were speaking | I was listening

Dependent clause | main clause

While you spoke | I listened

Dependent clause | main clause

Now, we turn to verb tense sequence to show the relationship between the clauses in each sentence. We start with the main clause.

When the main clause, "I *was listening*" which is Past Progressive and you want to show another continuous past action (the adverb "While" accomplishes this; it means as a conjunction, *during the time that*), use the Past Progressive "While you *were speaking*" in the dependent clause.

When the main clause, "I *listened*" is Past Tense, and you want to show another completed past action, use the Past Tense "While you *spoke*" in the dependent clause.

Verb Tense Sequence

http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/sequence.htm